# Read files from Stream

Tags: c#, web-services, stream, filestream

I posted two files to my custom web service. Now I need to read this stream into separate files.

I've sent an XML and a Text file and in the web service I read it as following:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
string xmls = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

I get the stream as string as following (I've also added the boundaries):

```
"\r\n------------------------------8cfd42d26566ff0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uplTheFile\"; filename=\"E:\\AJ\\Demo\\EktronSite2\\XMLFiles\\XMLFile.xml\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n﻿<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<note xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLFile.xsd\">\r\n  <ID>101</ID>\r\n</note>\r\n------------------------------8cfd42d26566ff0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uplTheFile\"; filename=\"C:\\TEMP\\log.txt\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\r\n------------------------------8cfd42d26566ff0\r\n"
```

I need to read the same into different files. For example I need the XML read to XmlDocument type and the text to .docx.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try this :

```
Stream xmlStream = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
Stream txtStream = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[1].InputStream;
```

Comment: I know how to read the StreamReader to a string, but how do I get the contend from Stream Object

Comment: Just use  StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(xmlStream );

Comment: Thanks it helped me. I had to google the whole day and was getting ways to post only and not to read at the service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use following function :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string path, string contents)
```

It will basically dumps your string into  file.

Comment: I guess the content should be the string that has the file data, but right now I am having contents of two files that are appended in a single string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
```